# Unable to watch Reward Video with Chartboost Integration

Tags: android, ads, chartboost, rewardedvideoad

I have used chartboost sdk for monetizing app as publisher,and was working fine but from last week I am facing issue of ASSETS_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE (Failed to download https://a2.chartboost.com/production/video_icon/c842af67839244ada54bb7ea8a80076f Error message=java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://a2.chartboost.com/production/video_icon/c842af67839244ada54bb7ea8a80076f),

Please suggest what should I do?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bug from Chartboost and it is In Progress to be solved, till that you can request for ads by following steps:

1. Chartboost **Dashboard**-> select your app
2. go to **APP SETTING** -> **Reward Video**
3. click button **Revert to Default** of section **Reward Currency Image (80x80px)**
4. uncheck **Show Pre-Roll Confirmation** and **Show Post-Roll Confirmation** from **Advance Setting** section

After or within one hour, try to request for ads.